# Rows selection in GridControl DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

In DevExpress 13 GridControl.TableView with a dynamic list when a row is deleted the row selection doesn't dissapear. It remains on the row which replaced the deleted one. When the selected row is deleted, how can I make the row selection dissapear automatically too?
I tried to implement it through GridControl.BeginDataUpdate and GridControl.EndDataUpdate., dut it does not work.

```
private bool _isAlreadyLoaded = false;

private void GridControl_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ThisViewModel != null
        && _isAlreadyLoaded == false)
    {
        ThisViewModel.GettingNewRow += RefreshCommSessionsList;

        _isAlreadyLoaded = true;
    }
}
//InitializeDataList - method that getting List for GridControl.TableView

public void RefreshCommSessionsList()
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var a = GridControl.GetSelectedRowHandles();
        int selectedRowHandle = -1;
        if (a.Any())
        {
            selectedRowHandle = GridControl.View.FocusedRowHandle;
        }
        GridControl.BeginDataUpdate();
        if (NewRowCount < 5 && ThisViewModel != null)
        {
            ThisViewModel.InitializeDataList();
            TableView.DataControl.SelectItem(selectedRowHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            GridControl.RefreshData();
            TableView.DataControl.SelectItem(selectedRowHandle);
        }
        GridControl.EndDataUpdate();
        NewRowCount++;
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GridControl.CurrentItem`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CurrentItemtopic) property. If you set its value to `null` then the row selection will dissapear.

```
GridControl.CurrentItem = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the FocusedRow of a Grid, use the GridView!

So if your GridView is named the same as your GridControl it would go as follows,

```
GridView.FocusedRowChanged(null, null);
//Replace "GridView" with your GridView's name
```